# How do I add a cloudformation security group ingress rule that refers to another security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following security group in a yaml template. I'd like to have the "SecurityGroupApplication" security group allow incoming connections from the "SecurityGroupBastion". However, the validate-template function of the aws client is telling me unhelpful information like "unsupported structure". Ok, but what is wrong with the structure? Ideas?

```
Resources:
  SecurityGroupBastion:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Bastion security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
      VpcId: !Ref vpcId
  SecurityGroupApplication:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Application security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref SecurityGroupBastion
          IpProtocol: tcp
```

Comment: How are you specifying the template to the awscli? What does your command line look like?

Comment: If you're using --template-body /users/bob/xyz then you should use --template-body file://users/bob/xyz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template works perfectly find for me, except that I had to specify the ports for the App security Group:

```
Resources:
  SecurityGroupBastion:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Bastion security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
      VpcId: vpc-abcd1234
  SecurityGroupApplication:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Application security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref SecurityGroupBastion
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
```

Answer (score 2):

Just if someone falls into this old question, now, there is a way to reference cross account SG in cloudformation, so if you want to add an SG ingress rule pointing to another AWS account just add the key `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` and the `account ID`.

i.e.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TargetSG:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: vpc-1a2b3c4d
      GroupDescription: Security group allowing ingress for security scanners
  InboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !GetAtt TargetSG.GroupId
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      SourceSecurityGroupId: sg-12345678 # SG in the other AWS account
      SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId: '123456789012' # Account ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `SecurityGroupApplication` to be a Security Group, then you should use `Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` instead of `Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress`. That is probably the cause of the "unsupported structure" error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did change this back and forth, and finally back as you suggested. And it still provides same error.

Answer (score 0):

Already covered but here is AWS' documentation for reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-securitygroup-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-ingress-sourcesecuritygroupownerid

> SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId
>
> [nondefault VPC] The AWS account ID for the source security group, if
> the source security group is in a different account. You can't specify
> this property with an IP address range. Creates rules that grant full
> ICMP, UDP, and TCP access.
>
> If you specify SourceSecurityGroupName or SourceSecurityGroupId and
> that security group is owned by a different account than the account
> creating the stack, you must specify the SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId;
> otherwise, this property is optional.